# Python Script For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have these python program:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():

    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").text = row.Document
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").caretPosition = 10
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0016/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/btnEDITFILTER").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/btnAPP_WL_SING").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/btn600_BUTTON").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").text = row.Position
    self.session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-HIGH").text = row.Position
    self.session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-HIGH").setFocus
    self.session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-HIGH").caretPosition = 3
    self.session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0016/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[10,0]").text = row.New_Price
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0016/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[10,0]").setFocus
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0016/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211/txtMEPO1211-NETPR[10,0]").caretPosition = 14
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
```

And I want to run this line:

```
self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press()
```

only once in the loop.

How do I run it once only? (only that line)

Comment: Have you tried to move it out of loop?

Comment: Create a boolean variable and set it to True outside the for loop. Inside the loop, check if the boolean variable is True, if so, then do the press and set the boolean variable to False. That should do the trick

Comment: This line of code is not dependent on `index` or `row`. Why do you need it inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) said, try moving the code outside the loop because that specific line has nothing to do with the loop in the first place. You are not using the `row` or the `index` for that line. So it makes no sense to keep it inside the loop unless you aren't telling us something.

However, to answer your question, you could create a boolean variable outside the loop to track if the loop has been run and do your action on the first try. Something like this:

```
firstRun = True
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").text = row.Document
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0003/ctxtMEPO_SELECT-EBELN").caretPosition = 10
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    if firstRun: # THIS IS TRUE on the first run
        self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press() # Do the click once.
        firstRun = False # Set it to False so that subsequent runs are not treated as first run.
    # Run All other clicks and stuff in your loop as usual.
```